# What can happen, when I don't regularize bias in machine learning, no need to write code for bias?

Tags: machine-learning

Well, I see some resolves about machine learning, all of them using regularize and write private code for bias, I think it is unnecessary. Instead, I write code for all weight (Theta) : Theta0, Theta1, ... to find grad and apply regularization for all Theta. 
Am I wrong ? Thank for all.

Answer (score 0):

Regularization should not be applied to bias of each layer, according to all online tutorials I have read.

And does "no need to write code for bias" mean there's no bias term when computing layers activations? I quickly made an experiment on a task I am implementing, and the model performance on the test set myteriously improves significantly without bias. But for different tasks the results and effects of bias are probably all different. Make some experiments to test if the performance on the test set is better or worse with or without biases.

Comment: Thank for your reply and I ask myself what happen if we apply regularization term for bias unit ?